# How to enable security in Cloudera distribution of Hadoop and Hbase?

Tags: .htaccess, security, hadoop, cloudera

I have installed CDH (Cloudera) Hadoop cluster, and have web admin panels on ports 50070, 50060, 50030, 50075, etc.

How I can enable something like .htaccess file to enable any simple security to access?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment to newer versions of Hadoop, but 0.x and 1.x releases use Jetty to serve up the web resources. I don't think they have the ability to implement the sort of security you are looking for out of the box.

Typically protecting access to resources like this (and the cluster in general) is achieved by putting all the nodes on an isolated network, with an edge node that people ssh to. From this point you can manage login to this edge node to prevent unauthorised access, and your users can tunnel connections through to the various web resources.

It's one way, there are probably others.

Comment: Thanks Chris! It's my situation, I have ssh to one master node, and just looking for ways to get web admin panels. Is it possible to browse lan resources through ssh to one machine?

Comment: Not sure i understand your question: "Is it possible to browse lan resources through ssh to one machine?"

Answer (score 0):

Thank's Chris, I got Idea.

The easy way to protect hadoop&hbase lan resources - I mean web admin, browse filesystem, hbase health, etc is to use SSH Tunnel,

First you need:

- remote ssh access to one your lan machine - for example: master
  has an ip - `192.168.10.5`
- on your local achine you make `ssh -D    localhost:12345
  user@lan_machine`
- in firefox your setup socks    proxy - `localhost:12345` (is better
  to use foxy proxy plugin)

after, you may access to your lan resources like your in this lan. For
   example tasktracker: `http://192.168.10.5:50060/tasktracker.jsp`